# How to create ASP.NET RecaptchaControl Custom template

Tags: asp.net, captcha

I would like to know how to create a RecaptchaControl template on my ASP.NET site.

I need to change the HTML of the control to fit RTL layout.

Here is the code for the control:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>
<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
    ID="recaptcha"
    Theme="custom"
    runat="server"
    PublicKey="YYYYYYY"
    PrivateKey="XXXXXXX"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a late reply, but probably the simplest way to go about this would be to use the CustomThemeWidget property of the recaptchacontrol. Here is a great tutorial on using it:

http://www.onequarterenglish.co.uk/using-a-custom-recaptcha-in-asp-net

Comment: The referenced page link generates a "This site cannot be reached" error message.

Answer (score 1):

Appeaars that there are some issues with rtl and recaptcha - [this link](http://drupal.org/node/1120812) pertain to drupal
but it seems with [custom themeing](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html) it may be posible. I am unsure how you would imleent it with a server control. You might have to dive into the source

Comment: Can I make a template of the control markup ? from the link you sent it seems they have full markup control over the layout of the control. I did not find a way to do it in the binarys of the ASP.NET.

Comment: You may have to go into the source of the control - you might have to disassempble it and then work backwards.

Comment: that is an over kill... does any one know of a simlper way ?